# Getting this error "Could not find or load main class com.liveqos.superbeam.desktop.SuperBeamApp" while trying to run a .sh file on linux

Tags: command-line, scripts, java, chmod

I am a new linux user and I am struck while attempting to run Super Beam. Whenever I use the commands:

```
chmod +x SuperBeam-5.0.3-linux.sh
sudo ./SuperBeam-5.0.3-linux.sh
```

to run the program, I get an error on terminal:

```
Could not find or load main class com.liveqos.superbeam.desktop.SuperBeamApp
```

Comment: How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How exactly did you install the software? As far as I can tell you just need to download the `tar.gz` from [superbe.am](https://superbe.am/for-pc/), unpack it, make `start-superbeam.sh` executable and run it. Where did you get your `.sh` file from?

Comment: Report the bug to whoever created this package. They didn't do their job correctly if this happens.